# How to use Dynamic Drawable instead of resource in DisplayImageOptions in Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

`DisplayImageOptions` take drawable resource id for these methods -

```
.showStubImage(R.drawable.default_grid_drawable)
.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.default_grid_drawable)
.showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_grid_drawable)
```

Can I use dynamically created `GradientDrawable` or `ShapeDrawable` instead of static resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can try to use `ImageLoadingListener.onLoadingStarted(...)` to set you drawable.

Comment: I modified the source is it ok with you?

Comment: Now I can use static resource like `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable)` or simply put dynamic `GradientDrawable` or `ShapeDrawable`.

Comment: You are free to use/change UIL sources as you want (according copyright :) ).

Comment: @Mihir Im facing the same problem as you have. can you please post your code?

Comment: I modified the source code a little bit. Here is the [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110577076/UniversalImageLoader.rar) for the modified library project. Its working absolutely fine.